# how to install cassandra on android

Tags: android, cassandra

I want to have a database running on android. For this i want to use cassandra.
what i did was donwnload Termux on my android, but have not been able to install cassandra. I want to use cassandra on the anroid, not send the data to another place.
i have tryed to include the repositorys to the repository list, like sayd on http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ , but i havnt been able to find /etc/apt/sources.list.d to inclue the repositorys.
any help is apreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never heard of anyone running it naively on an Android device, I'd be a little skeptical that it's possible, or at least practical.

Comment: Cassandra is database designed for handling a big amount of data on multiple nodes. Take another database for Android...

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be done. Plus, Cassandra is designed for very big data....billions of records. This is a bit of a naive question. You may want to start by studying some basic principles of application development and architecture